# Simulink Error in inputting From Workspace box

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to analyze the flow of products in a system by year. For instance, in the year 2005, there are 250 units entering the system, and after some processes, XXX of the units go out of the system as wastes; and then in the year 2006, there are 300 units entering the system.

I was trying to put a 31*2 matrix in the box From Workspace, and the first column is the year from 2005 to 2035, the second column is the data. But when I run the model, an error appeared like this:

> "Available formats are double non-complex matrix, a structure with or without time, or a structure with MATLAB timeseries as leaf nodes. All formats require the data to be finite (not Inf or NaN).

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Your data is actually not a matrix, but a table. You can use [`table2array`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2array.html) to convert it to a matrix, and then use that variable in the `From Workspace` block.

Depending on how you want to use the data you will have to set block settings appropriately, but without providing more details in your question about how you want to use the data, we cannot give the right settings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I was trying to do is, to analyze the flow of the products in the system by year. For instance, in the year 2005, there are 250 units entering the system, and after some processes, XXX of the units go out of the system as wastes; and then in the year 2006, there are 300 units entering the system, ... just like that.

Comment: @Bobet I copied your comment to the question body.